# Responsive Mode on the Free Prestashop Revolution Slider

Tags: slider, prestashop

I have downloaded a free **Prestashop Revolution Slider** from here:
http://www.yourbestcode.com/products/12-free-prestashop-revolution-slider.html

How do I enable **responsive** mode on this slider while using a custom theme?

Answer (score -1):

To switch this to responsive mode, you need to enable responsive mode at backeoffice and make your website front page div to be flexible (not fixed with)
I have installed the module with responsive mode and it's fine.

cheer!